# Faster Sleep Timeout for Andoid Phone

Tags: android

In the configuration on my android phone, I currently have my phone set to lock the screen and sleep after 15 seconds of inactivity. There [are options](http://www.androidauthority.com/screen-timeout-572050/) to have it sleep in 30 seconds, a minute, 30 minutes, etc.

For me, 15 seconds is to long. I want the phone to sleep in about 5 seconds.

Is there an app for this?

Comment: Is your device rooted ?

Comment: Try this app - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.lhoer0.screentimeout&hl=en

Comment: @wingedpanther Thanks for your answer. It isn't rooted. Tried that app, it isn't able to shorten it lower than 15 seconds; but it works otherwise.

Comment: IIRC, You can reduce the sleep time to any value(1s,2s ..5 s etc) in the app itself there is an edit option

Comment: @wingedpanther When I went in the app and set it to a value >15s, it worked fine. When I set it to 5 s, it goes to sleep at 15 s. When I set it to 10 s, it goes to sleep at 15 s. For any value <15, it set the sleep time to 15. Maybe I should contact the author?

Comment: Yes, just give a heads up to the developer

Comment: Everyone - the app suggested by WingedPanther works great.

Comment: Great... What was the issue?

Comment: Got a different used phone. It turns out the other one had a bunch of issues.